# Monitor creation of SQL logins

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to check which (domain/sql) users have created logins for a SQL Server instance? 
I have tried creating a new login and  checked SQL Server logs but I couldn't find the new entry in the logs.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1085631/Hidden-gems-of-DEFAULT-TRACE-in-SQL-Server

Comment: Do you mean created when or created by?

Comment: I mean created by, what user created login X

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query for created when.

```
SELECT
    [name],
    [create_date],
    [type_desc]
FROM
    sys.server_principals
WHERE
    [type] IN 
        (
        'S', -- = SQL Login
        'U' -- = Windows Login
        ) 
ORDER BY
    [create_date]
```

You could narrow down who the login was created by maybe by starting with who has sysadmin or serveradmin access. You can find that with this query:

```
SELECT
    [name]
FROM
    sys.syslogins
WHERE
    [sysadmin] = 1
    OR [serveradmin] = 1
```

Fields for the other high level server roles are included in the same view.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but unfortunately this is not what I am asking. If my question is not possible in any way, (I'm a SQL newbie, so I dont know if it is) that's an acceptable answer to my question.

Comment: Hey doenoe, there's nothing that you can query historically to find this out. However you could setup a service broker event to record things like this as an event when it happens. Or as an instance/server level trigger to notify you or write to a separate log table of the ORIGINAL_LOGIN that created the login. Anything is possible. Just maybe a little more technical to achieve than you were hoping for.